# Pynmea2 AttributeError `NoneType` object has no attribute `num_sats`

Tags: python

When trying to create a conditional statement i get this error. I have tried many things over the last week to get this working but everything i try is failing.
Can anyone shed some light if this is specific to pynmea nodule?

````py
def parse_gps(incoming_data):

    if incoming_data.find("GGA") > 0:
        data = pynmea2.parse(incoming_data)
        print("Timestamp: %s // Lat: %s  // Lon: %s // Satellites: %s  " % (data.timestamp, data.latitude,
                                                                            data.longitude, data.num_sats))
        return data


while True:
    gps_fix = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    gps_data = parse_gps(gps_fix)
    if gps_data.num_sats > 7:
        break
    else:
        print("No data")```


Should find a fix of satellites greater than 7 in order to gain a valid fix then break.
````

Comment: if `incoming_data.find("GGA") == 0` you will return `None`

Comment: Would it be wise to create another function away from this one then? Since ("GGA") > 0 is crucial to strip NMEA setences coming from the GPS reciever

Comment: You need to ask yourself what do you want to do when `incoming_data.find("GGA") == 0`  WHat you are doing now does not work...

Comment: My apolgies i quickly realised what you had said. Its been a long night. I have tried !=0 `is not None` I am struggling to find a logical way to create a condtional to break.

Comment: @StephenRauch could you provide an example of how i might fix this if you wouldn't mind? Thank You. As you stated i need to deal with the issue when ("GGA") == 0 which according the serial monitor output shouldn't happen because GGA sentences coming from GPS module are always present. But for the error to be happening proves otherwise. Very confused.

Answer (score 0):

````py
while True:
    gps_fix = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    gps_data = parse_gps(gps_fix)
    if gps_data is not None and int(gps_data.num_sats) > 7:
        break```

After a few errors about str and int i finally managed to work out the fix.
````